# rails Remove dependent records whose parent records are no longer exist

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database

This may look like a silly question, you would just say use `has_many :child_model, dependent: :destroy`

Yes, of course we have added that now.

But the problem is we already have huge records(~ 3 million) of `child_model` with `parent_model_id` but some of those(~60k) records have `parent_model_id` with `ParentModel.exists?(parent_model_id)`returning false

I could run a migration looping through all the records in `child_model` and checking for the above condition, but I'm wondering if there's a way to fetch the records from sql,

Something which would filter `ChildModel.joins(:parent_model)` from `ChildModel.all` and give us the rest.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you run a migration you will not be looping the records (Maybe schdeuler?), but running a SQL statement to delete those records.

```
execute "DELETE FROM child_model WHERE parent_model_id NOT IN (SELECT id FROM parent_model)"
```

Comment: That looks great, that was what I have been looking for, thanks.